# Making a thread safe class from an abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, thread-safety, abstract-class

A question of design. I know that this method is thread safe, but from a design point of view, is there any better way to do this?

I have an abstract class (not thread safe):

```
public abstract class Class1
{
    protected someobject myobject;

    public Class1()
    {
       myobject = new someoject();
    }

    public virtual void proc1()
    {
      // do something with my object
    }

   public virtual void proc2()
    {
      // do something with my object
    }

  public virtual void proc3()
    {
      // do something with my object
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a descendent from this class that needs to be thread safe, so I do:

```
public class Class2: Class1
{
    private static readonly object obj = new object();


    public override void  proc1()
    {
      lock(obj)
      {
          base.proc1();
      }
    }

   public override void proc2()
   {
      lock(obj)
      {
          base.proc2();
      }
    }

   public override void proc3()
    {
      lock(obj)
      {
          base.proc3();
      }
    }
}
```

I could make the base thread safe but I have some other classes that inherits from the same base and don't need thread safety, so I don't want to force thread safety into it. Any problems with this kind of design? It's a bit tedious if the base has many public members....

Comment: Usually this is done by encapsulation rather than inheritance: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,c66df6f36c131877  You have the same amount of code to write, but at least you don't have to mark all the base methods as virtual

Comment: Sure, but the reason why those are virtual are because some other class can modify the behavior of the base, so they need to stay virtual.

Comment: If the procs are only accessing instance members, I would make the lock object an instance object too, otherwise you are unnecessarily locking calls that don't interfere with each other. I.e, it would be okay if `a.proc1()` and `b.proc1()` would be called at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to operate with `Class1` (or a descendant class for that matter)  in a thread safe manner, you should use encapsulation instead of inheritance as Kevin Gosse stated. Inheritance should not be used in this way, because if `Class1` has more methods that are not virtual (maybe even public) that will change the object's internal state you will not have any control on them. You should take and encapsulate a class that inherits `Class1` and then expose methods that will be called as a thread safe methods.

Even if you do control `Class1` design, it will be a poor design to think of the Thread safe inheritor (`Class2`) every time you are adding or changing `Class1`'s methods

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to deduce the potential usage of your code but from general considerations standpoint I'd highlight the following issues:

1. Responsibility. I'm looking at `Class2` code and see that it does nothing additional in compare to the base class apart from race condition protection of the base class methods. Usually we tend impose a thread safety in regards of specific state in order to ensure the state consistence under concurrent access conditions. But in this case the `Class2` simply isn't aware whether a behavior it protects may or may not lead to the race conditions. What if `Class1` is modified in the way when thread safety isn't more needed - we'll have redundant locks in the `Class2` class (or will remove them having such indirect coupling with `Class1`). What if `Class1` is extended with additional methods or even worse someone decide to add extra thread safety into `Class1` by another lock object (in worst case we may have deadlocks). So each time we do such changes in the `Class1` we also have to check `Class2` code as well to make sure that nothing is broken, in other words we have tight coupling between these classes only because `Class2` has responsibility which shouldn't belong to it.
2. LSP. When we're talking about a hierarchy of classes we usually bear in mind that there shouldn't be different requirements of usage the hierarchy contract regardless of what type of the hierarchy is used. Having in a hierarchy thread safe and not thread safe classes imposes additional restrictions to usage of this hierarchy. In particular a consumer should be aware of what type of instance it deals with under what circumstances, which potentially excludes the number of scenarios the LSP-compliant hierarchy can be used in. As en example a consumer won't be able to use the collections of `Class1` in generic scenarios unless it definitely knowns that scenarios are thread safe.

As general recommendations:

1. I'd try to avoid introducing a behavior in sub-classes which may depend on context in which the sub classes can be used. I'd try to make the entire hierarchy consistent: either all classes in the hierarchy are thread-safe or they all aren't.
2. If some classes in your hierarchy require thread safety and some don't, it can be an indicator of low cohesion of hierarchy contract. I'd try to decompose the base class and sub-classes into smaller pieces which may imply multiple contracts and possibly hierarchies.
3. If the base class or other classes keep the state which potentially can be used in different concurrency contexts and it's still difficult to achieve homogeneous hierarchy from the thread-safety perspective, I'd consider moving synchronization logic outside of classes in the hierarchy and to leave this responsibility to a consumer.

Answer (score -2):

Code in a superclass (abstract or otherwise) is not thread safe in s subclass (extends).  Use encapsulation instead.

Also note that if you have changes to make to the classes you can do that in a synchronized method (like gets and sets below but more complex).

Best make class1 & class2 immutable and just replace them when they change.

Encapsulation (think beans)

```
public class{
  Class1 class1;
  Class2 class2
  public synchronized set1(Class1 class1){
    this.class1 = class1;
  }
  public A synchronized get1(){
    return class1;
  }
  public synchronized set2(Class2 class2){
    this.class1 = class2;
  }
  public A synchronized get2(){
    return class2;
  }
}
```